# JAXB Exception: is not known to this context

Tags: java, jaxb, websphere

I've problem with JAXB, when I make soap call, it return a jaxb exception: 
the request is not known to this context, but the wsdl is successfully created by maven.
My class:

This is my PROVIDER:

```
@Service
public class ChangeKeysServiceProvider extends GenericServiceProvider {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ChangeKeysServiceProvider.class);

    public ChangeKeysServiceResponse doService(ChangeKeysServiceRequest request) {
        if (logger.isTraceEnabled()) {
            logger.trace("Starting request");
        }

        BSRChangeKeysServiceProxy proxy = getProxy(getProxyClass());
        proxy.setParams(request.getFilterIn());
        proxy.setHeaderAttributes(fillServiceHeader(request.getServiceContext()));
        ChangeKeysServiceResponse response = null;
            try {
                proxy.performService();
                response = new ChangeKeysServiceResponse();

            } catch (ServiceException e) {
                response = new ChangeKeysServiceResponse();
                response.setReturnCode(e.getErrorCode());
                response.addErrorMessage(e.getMessage());
                logger.error("An error occurred invoking  request", e);
            }

            if (logger.isTraceEnabled()) {
                logger.trace("Starting request...DONE!");
            }

        return response;
    }

        protected Class <BSRChangeKeysServiceProxy> getProxyClass() {
        return BSRChangeKeysServiceProxy.class;
        }
}
```

This is my Request:

```
public class ChangeKeysServiceRequest extends GenericServiceRequest {


    private ParamCambioPwd filterIn;

    public ParamCambioPwd getFilterIn() {
        return filterIn;
    }
    public void setFilterIn(ParamCambioPwd filterIn) {
        this.filterIn = filterIn;
    }
}
```

(in ParamCambioPwd I have only Get and Set about String, long and boolean.)

when I make a SOAP call, it returns following exception:

```
[11/07/14 15.01.14:475 CEST] 00000085 RemoteExcepti E   CNTR0020E: EJB threw an unexpected (non-declared) exception during invocation of method "ChangeKeys" on bean "BeanId(IB_MultiChannelServices_EAR#IB_MultiChannelServices.war#GWSicurezza, null)". Exception data: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException:x.service.provider.modificapasswordaccesso.ChangeKeysServiceRequest is not known to this context
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.createWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:175)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.makeWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:70)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.makeWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:128)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.impl.alt.DocLitWrappedMinimalMethodMarshaller.demarshalRequest(DocLitWrappedMinimalMethodMarshaller.java:273)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.server.dispatcher.JavaBeanDispatcher.createRequestParameters(JavaBeanDispatcher.java:322)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.server.dispatcher.JavaBeanDispatcher.invoke(JavaBeanDispatcher.java:102)
    at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.server.dispatcher.EJBBeanDispatcher.invoke(EJBBeanDispatcher.java:80)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.server.EndpointController.invoke(EndpointController.java:111)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.server.JAXWSMessageReceiver.receive(JAXWSMessageReceiver.java:161)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:208)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
    at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.WASAxis2Servlet.doPost(WASAxis2Servlet.java:1570)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1225)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:775)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:457)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
    at x.ws.logging.SoapLoggingFilter.doFilter(SoapLoggingFilter.java:70)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:928)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1025)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:908)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:283)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1815)
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: x.service.provider.modificapasswordaccesso.ChangeKeysServiceRequest is not known to this context
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getBeanInfo(JAXBContextImpl.java:642)
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.getBeanInfo(UnmarshallerImpl.java:568)
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:353)
    at com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.jaxb.unmarshal.UnmarshallerProxy.unmarshal(UnmarshallerProxy.java:198)
    at org.apache.axis2.datasource.jaxb.JAXBDSContext$2.run(JAXBDSContext.java:688)
    at org.apache.axis2.java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:76)
    at org.apache.axis2.datasource.jaxb.JAXBDSContext.unmarshalByType(JAXBDSContext.java:592)
    at org.apache.axis2.datasource.jaxb.JAXBDSContext.unmarshal(JAXBDSContext.java:351)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.message.databinding.impl.JAXBBlockImpl._getBOFromReader(JAXBBlockImpl.java:96)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.message.impl.BlockImpl._getBOFromOM(BlockImpl.java:476)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.message.databinding.impl.JAXBBlockImpl._getBOFromOM(JAXBBlockImpl.java:136)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.message.impl.BlockImpl.getBusinessObject(BlockImpl.java:148)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.message.impl.XMLSpineImpl._getBlockFromOMElement(XMLSpineImpl.java:616)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.message.impl.XMLSpineImpl.getBodyBlock(XMLSpineImpl.java:320)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.message.impl.XMLPartBase.getBodyBlock(XMLPartBase.java:509)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.message.impl.MessageImpl.getBodyBlock(MessageImpl.java:512)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.impl.alt.DocLitWrappedMinimalMethodMarshaller.getPDElementsForDocLitWrappedMinimal(DocLitWrappedMinimalMethodMarshaller.java:868)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.impl.alt.DocLitWrappedMinimalMethodMarshaller.demarshalRequest(DocLitWrappedMinimalMethodMarshaller.java:246)
    ... 39 more

[11/07/14 15.01.14:478 CEST] 00000085 AxisEngine    E org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine receive javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: x.provider.modificapasswordaccesso.ChangeKeysServiceRequest is not known to this context
                                 org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: x.provider.modificapasswordaccesso.ChangeKeysServiceRequest is not known to this context
    at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.server.JAXWSMessageReceiver.receive(JAXWSMessageReceiver.java:242)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:208)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
    at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.WASAxis2Servlet.doPost(WASAxis2Servlet.java:1570)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1225)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:775)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:457)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
    at x.logging.SoapLoggingFilter.doFilter(SoapLoggingFilter.java:70)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:928)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1025)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:908)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:283)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1815)
Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: x.service.provider.modificapasswordaccesso.ChangeKeysServiceRequest is not known to this context
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.createWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:175)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.makeWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:70)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.makeWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:128)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.impl.alt.DocLitWrappedMinimalMethodMarshaller.demarshalRequest(DocLitWrappedMinimalMethodMarshaller.java:273)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.server.dispatcher.JavaBeanDispatcher.createRequestParameters(JavaBeanDispatcher.java:322)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.server.dispatcher.JavaBeanDispatcher.invoke(JavaBeanDispatcher.java:102)
    at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.server.dispatcher.EJBBeanDispatcher.invoke(EJBBeanDispatcher.java:80)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.server.EndpointController.invoke(EndpointController.java:111)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.server.JAXWSMessageReceiver.receive(JAXWSMessageReceiver.java:161)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: x.service.provider.modificapasswordaccesso.ChangeKeysServiceRequest is not known to this context
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getBeanInfo(JAXBContextImpl.java:642)
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.getBeanInfo(UnmarshallerImpl.java:568)
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:353)
    at com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.jaxb.unmarshal.UnmarshallerProxy.unmarshal(UnmarshallerProxy.java:198)
    at org.apache.axis2.datasource.jaxb.JAXBDSContext$2.run(JAXBDSContext.java:688)
    at org.apache.axis2.java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:76)
    at org.apache.axis2.datasource.jaxb.JAXBDSContext.unmarshalByType(JAXBDSContext.java:592)
    at org.apache.axis2.datasource.jaxb.JAXBDSContext.unmarshal(JAXBDSContext.java:351)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.message.databinding.impl.JAXBBlockImpl._getBOFromReader(JAXBBlockImpl.java:96)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.message.impl.BlockImpl._getBOFromOM(BlockImpl.java:476)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.message.databinding.impl.JAXBBlockImpl._getBOFromOM(JAXBBlockImpl.java:136)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.message.impl.BlockImpl.getBusinessObject(BlockImpl.java:148)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.message.impl.XMLSpineImpl._getBlockFromOMElement(XMLSpineImpl.java:616)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.message.impl.XMLSpineImpl.getBodyBlock(XMLSpineImpl.java:320)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.message.impl.XMLPartBase.getBodyBlock(XMLPartBase.java:509)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.message.impl.MessageImpl.getBodyBlock(MessageImpl.java:512)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.impl.alt.DocLitWrappedMinimalMethodMarshaller.getPDElementsForDocLitWrappedMinimal(DocLitWrappedMinimalMethodMarshaller.java:868)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.impl.alt.DocLitWrappedMinimalMethodMarshaller.demarshalRequest(DocLitWrappedMinimalMethodMarshaller.java:246)
    ... 39 more
```

How I can fix this problem?

Comment: It likely means when you create your `JAXBContext` (which I can't see from this code), you don't tell it about your `ChangeKeysServiceRequest` class, hence your error.

Comment: Hi, the error doesn't seem to be related to the ServiceContext class, because other services, made ​​in the same way, work!
(currently I own only the .class about ServiceContext)

Comment: I think we'll need to see more code in order to be of help...

Comment: @Mr.Noise have you got the solution?